# PostgreSQL transaction level guarantees for foreign key consistency in read only transactions

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Application **A** (think exporter) needs to read all rows of all tables from a running PostgreSQL database. Meanwhile Application **B** (think web application) continues to do reads and writes.

Table `child` has an optional foreign key to `parent`.

I've had trouble with the following access pattern:

- **A**: `BEGIN TRANSACTION`
- **A**: `SELECT * FROM parent`
- **B**: `BEGIN TRANSACTION`
- **B**: `INSERT INTO parent`
- **B**: `INSERT INTO child -- has foreign key to inserted parent`
- **B**: `COMMIT`
- **A**: `SELECT * FROM child -- I do not want to receive the inserted child here`

Application **A** breaks because it reads a `child` for which it could not read the `parent`. Therefore I do not want that **A** reads the `child` row inserted by **B**.

As far as I understand `REPEATABLE_READ` does not give me any guarantees here, since I did not already read the `child` table in this transaction. As far as I understand this is not considered a phantom read either for the same reason.

- Does `SERIALIZABLE` guarantee that **A** does not read the new `child` row?
- Do I need to resort to application logic in **A** to discard `child` rows with invalid references to `parent`?

Comment: If A runs in repeatable read, it will not see any new (or changed or deleted) rows  that were inserted afterthe transaction started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start transaction A with

```
START TRANSACTION READ ONLY ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Then all statements in that transaction will see the same state (snapshot) of the database, no matter what was modified by concurrent transactions.

I added the `READ ONLY` only because you said that A was, it is not necessary for it to work.